# How to know who downvoted you?

Tags: discussion

Few minutes ago someone downvoted all my question and answers in stackoverflow.com.

[My reputation today](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1964435/math?tab=reputation)

As you can see in the picture:
[image: bullying]

It's unethical, drops my reputation and my tags points..

I would like to know who did it, why and how to revert this?

I appreciate.

**EDIT**

I didn't know about the meta sites, I already created one account for me and will post properly in the next time I have a similar situation. I kind of freaked out and made things hurried. I posted in the wrong place I know, don't need to downvote this question anymore.. This situation is done. Thanks.

Comment: This belongs on [meta] rather than here.  If this was one person serially downvoting you then it should be caught and reverted automatically after a few hours.

Comment: I appreciate, will try to move to there. Thanks.

Comment: Serial downvoting should be caught and rectified *at some point* [Serial downvoting equals loss of reputation for offender?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113571/serial-downvoting-equals-loss-of-reputation-for-offender)

Comment: This is on a site meta, so downvotes don't mean much more than a metaphorical [cone of shame](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R58kSuIhURI). I do hope you keep calm and post on the correct site in future. There are checks and balances to handle people acting like idiots and bulk downvoting, thankfully

Comment: Ok, I'm calm. I do not like the cone of shame either, but it is ok, lol.

Comment: Down-voted for accepting an "answer" that didn't answer your own question!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a script that runs every night (UTC) that should revert all those downvotes.
There will be no other consequences for you.

The user who serially downvoted you, however, might get a friendly reminder from us not to do it again.

(Then again, this is your Stack Overflow account, not your Super User one, so you'd have to have a Stack Overflow mod check it out… not sure why you posted this on SU in the first place. Your question should have been posted on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), just so you know for the future.)

Comment: Thank you very much, I was a kind of afflicted with this situation, I wondered that it couldn't be reverted, I'll wait for the UTC midnight so.

Comment: No problem. Just wait a day or so, and if it doesn't revert, flag one of your Stack Overflow posts for moderator attention to have them check it out again.

Comment: I posted in Superuser because this is related to computer, lol. Didn't know about the meta sites. Then when it moved it was moved to meta super user, instead of meta stackoverflow. I think it shouldn't be moved to there, I was already creating my account at Meta Stackoverflow to deleted my question at superuser and create there, that was when my question migrated to here.

Comment: @Math Even if there was no meta, web sites or web apps are off topic on Super User.

Comment: That's true. The first thought that came into my head is that it didn't belong to stackoverflow. As I said, I freaked, somehow I thought is was related to superuser. Thanks.

Comment: `There will be no other consequences for you`, actually.. I've just had my reputation back, the downvotes are still there..

Comment: @Math They are not "still there", they are just listed in your history for the day they occurred (just for your reference), but as you can see in today's events, they were reversed.

Comment: Well, they're actually there. If you open the questions or answers you will see many `-1` where it should be `0`. Even more, I have a lots of `-1` in the tags too, they weren't recalculated. Will it maybe recalculated in the next midnight? One simple example where it was `0` previously and it is `-1` so far: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827556/how-do-i-run-bcdedit-from-my-c-program/17858721#17858721

Comment: @Math That particular post you've linked me to has zero votes, i.e. nobody voted on it: http://i.stack.imgur.com/eLrdu.png – so you're probably seeing some old data, caching issues on your side maybe?

Comment: @slhck Well, it updated recently. It is `0` now, but when I posted it was `-1`. This was the first to refresh, few hours after this comment. Then, few hours later the first one, all were updated. Everything is perfect now. Thanks!!

Comment: well, i experience it recently and go myself , find post id, find upvoted, downvoted, postids, usersid, ..etc in https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new and found nothing, :D

Comment: Down-voted for *not answering the question*.